# Black tint on NSMenu items

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am struggling to find a way of replicating a black tinted `NSMenu`. I would like the items in the button to have this style:
[image]

Does this involve subclassing `NSMenu` and if so, how would I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `appearance` property of `NSPopUpButton`.

*Swift:*

```
myPopUpButton.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
```

Objective-C:

```
myPopUpButton.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
```

The `appearance` property can be applied to any subclass of `NSView` (buttons, scrollViews etc.) and `NSWindows`.

Comment: but what about a NSMenu? The appearance property does not work with that class

Comment: No, this is for NSPopUpButton.

Comment: NSMenu automatically adopts its 'host view' appearance.